# onboard onscreen keyboard missing key symbols

Tags: lxde, onboard

I installed the package onboard with all required dependencies. However, the following key symbols are not displayed correctly (please see the attached screenshot): TAB, CAPS LOCK, left and right SHIFT and ENTER. What can I do to correct the problem? I am using LXDE on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Thank you.[image]

I replaced the "onboard" with "florence" virtual keyboard, which works impeccably.
[image]

Comment: Try changing font of onboard. Click the bottom right 3 lines key in onboard -> theme -> customize theme -> labels - > change font to popularly used ones

Comment: I was thinking that some fonts package is missing. I've tried changing the fonts of onboard, however it had absolutely no effect on correcting the problem with the key symbols. Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove and Use Muon package manager to re install, available in official repositories.

Comment: onboard is available in official repositories,  try to reinstall through terminal if muon package manager is not already installed with lxde, muon came already installed in lubuntu

Comment: I use "Synaptic Package Manager" and / or "LXTerminal" to manage the software. "Muon" is a part of KDE and is Qt based. I use LXDE, which is GTK2 based. I don't see how installing "muon" would help. When I tried to install "muon", it drags so many dependencies (KDE and Qt packages) completely irrelevant to my system. To be exact - 109 new packages that take 108 MB of disk space. No, thank you. I would rather install the "florence" instead of "onboard".

Comment: remove reboot and install again onboard through terminal. I said this previous comment too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however after following your advice nothing has changed: $ sudo apt purge onboard $ sudo apt autoremove Then after reboot: $ sudo apt install onboard (reinstall did not change anything). I think some packages are missing, but which ones?

Comment: does the language support fully installed English and English us languages ?

Comment: The only locale installed is "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" It is uncommented in "/etc/locale.gen" file. When I run "locale -a", the output is:                                               "C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX"              I installed "florence" keyboard and it displays all key symbols correctly.

Comment: open languages support, if it says incomplete , update needed, do it

Comment: I gave up on the "onboard", purged it from my system and installed "florence" florence (0.6.3-1.2) [universe] https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/florence (extensible and scalable virtual keyboard for X), which is impeccable and more customizable than "onboard".

Answer (score 0):

[image]The solution that worked for me was to install the package "fonts-dejavu-core". After installing the "fonts-dejavu-core", all the symbols display correctly.